# How to track the clicks in html elements using Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, onclick

I have multiple div, select and span html tags, with unique IDs and classes. Each div and span have onclick and use as slides and buttons.

I would like to track the no. of clicks on each div, select and span to know which div is being clicked the most.

How do I do this with Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

you should use GA event tracking https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

An event is designd specificlly for what you want

> Events are user interactions with content that can be tracked independently from a web page or a screen load. Downloads, mobile ad clicks, gadgets, Flash elements, AJAX embedded elements, and video plays are all examples of actions you might want to track as Events.

since you have an onclick for each element, just place a ga event in it, for example:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'click on element', 'div', 'id = my_id');
```

of course, you could to it with one function like this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('div,span,select').forEach(function(elem,index){
   elem.addEventListener('click',function(){
      var myId = elem.id;
      var tagName = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
      ga('send', 'event', 'click on element', tagName, myId );
   },false)
});
```

be advised tough that if you have nested div's - a click on the internal one will bubble to it's wrappers and create multiple events

Comment: Like this, E.g. `<div class="slider-selection" onclick="sliders.term.Move(window.event); ga('send', 'event', 'click on element', 'div', 'class= slider-selection');"></div>`?

Comment: exactly. you'll be able to see it under 'real time' -> 'events' in you're google analytics immediately

Comment: so i will combine the existing onclick function and the ga in every div/span/select that have a onlick event?

Comment: Yep. you can also use my function to automatically add eventListeners to all div's, span's and select's